# Returning a value to the main method

Tags: java

I am building a program that calculates and outputs values for: interest rates of 1% after 5 years for the values ranging from $1000-$20000 (1000, 2000, 3000, etc) with no compounding.

Ex)  1000 would be 1050, and 2000 would be 2100 (formula of A = P (1 + rt)).

At the current point, I am trying to write my code in such a way that when run, it lists all the values from 1000 - 20000 on different lines vertically, followed by all the values after the interest with no compounding takes affect:

1000
2000
...
20000
1050.0
2100.0
...
21000.0

(the above numbers are meant to appear vertically one below the other)

One of the items that I am trying to teach myself is the returning of a value from a method back to the main method.  In this case, my calculateAmountNoCompounding method has a return value that I set to `double testValue = (j * (1 + .01 * NUMBER_OF_YEARS));.  Yet when I try to return it to the main method by placing it in a print line function, I get the error ".class expected".  I also get this same error on the actual return statement in line 25.  Is there a simple and effective way to process this problem?

```
public class DepositCalculator {

public static final double ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE = 1.0;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_YEARS = 5;
public static final int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;
public static final int LOW_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT = 1000;
public static final int HIGH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT = 20000;
public static final int DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= HIGH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT - DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT; i = i + DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT) {
        System.out.println(LOW_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT + i);

    }     
    System.out.println(double testValue);

}

public static double calculateAmountNoCompounding(double deposit, double annualInterestRate, int numberOfYears) {

    for (double j = LOW_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT; j <= HIGH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT - DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT; j = j + DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT) {
        double testValue = (j * (1 + .01 * NUMBER_OF_YEARS));
    }
    return double testValue;
}

}
```

Comment: Since this is a large topic to explore, I think the Java tutorials [*Variables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and [*Returning a value from a method*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) will be helpful to learn these concepts from the ground up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't call `calculateAmountNoCompounding` in `main`.
2. `double` is a class here, so write it `Double`.
3. You should init `Double testValue;` above the `for` loop so that it is visible when you want to return it.
4. Calling an existing variable should be done without specifying the type. You can't do such `return double testValue;`, just do `return testValue;`. Because of `3.`, Java already knows that testValue is a double. The same applies to `System.out.println(double testValue);`.

Comment: `double` is not "a class", it's a primitive.  Using `Double` uses the corresponding wrapper class, and adds needless overhead.  There's nothing wrong with sticking with `double`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `return testValue;` and not `return double testValue`. Also you need to declare the variable testValue outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have "double" before the print or return statements.

The return should just be testValue and the print either the value that was returned:

```
double answer = calculateAmountNoCompounding(...);
System.out.println(answer);
```

or can print directly

```
System.out.println(calculateAmountNoCompounding(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I don't really want to give you the answer to all of this. But I have used your code and put an example in there

```
public class DepositCalculator {

public static final double ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE = 1.0;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_YEARS = 5;
public static final int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;
public static final int LOW_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT = 1000;
public static final int HIGH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT = 20000;
public static final int DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double result = 0.0;
    double deposit = 0.0;
    double annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    int numberOfYears = 0;

    //  you need to think about this
    /*for (int i = 0; i <= HIGH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT - DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT; i = i + DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT) {
      //  System.out.println(LOW_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT + i);

    }*/    

    //  you need to set the deposit amount, annualinterestrate and number of years

    //result = calculateAmountNoCompounding(deposit, annualInterestRate, numberOfYears);

    //  here is an example deposit is 5000, annual interest is 10 and numberofyears is 5
    result = calculateAmountNoCompounding(5000, 10, 5);



    System.out.println("result is " +result);
}

public static double calculateAmountNoCompounding(double deposit, double annualInterestRate, int numberOfYears) {
    double testValue = 0.0;
    //  you need to think about this
    //for (double j = LOW_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT; j <= HIGH_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT - DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT; j = j + DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_INCREMENT) {
        testValue = (deposit * (1 + .01 * numberOfYears));
    //}
    return testValue;
}

}
```

I hope that helps.